# php - if array key is in another arrays value

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry if this question is worded incorrectly or doesn't make any sense. What I am trying to do is write an if statement that checks if:

```
array(6) {
    [5]=>
    string(17) "Quality Assurance"
    [6]=>
    string(7) "Analyst"
    [7]=>
    string(19) "Developer/Front end"
    [8]=>
    string(18) "Developer/Back end"
    [9]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    [10]=>
    string(2) "hi"
}
```

Any of those keys, in this case, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 is in:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#195 (2) {
       ["labour_type_id"]=>
       int(5)
       ["required_labour_type_hours"]=>
       int(40)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#193 (2) {
       ["labour_type_id"]=>
       int(6)
       ["required_labour_type_hours"]=>
       int(80)
    }
}
```

This second arrays "labour_type_id".

In this example, 5 and 6 would match.

I am trying to use the in_array() function but I am not sure how to access the labour_type_id of the second array.

My best attempt at the moment:

```
        @foreach($labourTypes as $id => $name)
            @if(in_array($id, $reqLabourTypes->labour_type_id))
```

Where labourTypes is the first array, and reqLabourTypes is the 2nd array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cleaned up this little search for you to try and find it as you require:

```
$new = array_filter(array_map(function(&$item) use($requiredLabour, $labourTypes){

    $key = array_search($item, $labourTypes);
    foreach($requiredLabour as $elem){
        if($elem['labour_type_id'] == $key) {

            return array(
                $key => $item,
                'options' => $elem
            );

        }
    }

}, $labourTypes));
```

Everything will be accessible in `$new` if found. It returns:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [5] => Quality Assurance
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [labour_type_id] => 5
                    [required_labour_hours] => 40
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [6] => Analyst
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [labour_type_id] => 6
                    [required_labour_hours] => 40
                )

        )

)
```

The above is just the output, you can change it to whatever you need it to be by simply editing the `return array(.....` inside to whatever you require.

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#fyoTWoU5p)

Comment: Would it be possible for the new array to also take the corresponding required_labour_hours from the previous example?

Comment: Awesome thanks! How could I access the required_labour_hours from the new array?

Comment: Simply loop through the array with foreach, and access it, or direct call if you know the hours haha `$new[5]['options']['required_labour_hours']`

Comment: THANK YOU! I managed to implement it to my generated checkbox/input field finally. I've been struggling with this all day thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Beautiful! Congrats and glad I could help!